# Looking for finding attribute grammar for red-black tree

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree, context-free-grammar, red-black-tree, formal-languages

I have a recursive with inorder traversal grammar like this. `T--> L | TNT`
For a red-black tree which `T` is `Binary tree` and `L` is `Leaf` and `N` is `Node`.

As I search, each node is defined as a pair(color, value). I am trying to find 2 things.

1. I want to extend the grammar to become an attribute grammar, which checks if the conditions of a red/black tree are satisfied or not. The problem is I do not know how should I add the conditions of red-black to the grammar?
2. Finding synthesized and inherited attributes of the grammar.

Comment: That grammar is ambiguous and an attribute grammar does not usually resolve ambiguities. Is that your intention? You certainly need a black-depth synthesized attribute; if you allow bottom as a value, that's probably it.

Comment: I searched a lot to find CFG that first recognises a binary tree with inorder traversal and after that to extend it to an attribute grammar. The problem is, there is not even a starting point on the Internet which I can use. That s why I used this grammar

Answer (score 1):

The production

```
T → T N T
```

is (exponentially) ambiguous, since there is no indication whether the left or the right `T` should be expanded first.

Since `N` includes the colour, we could simply propagate the colour with the parse, in case it provides more information. (This is equivalent to synthesizing a colour attribute for each `T` by copying the colour attribute of the `N`, or black for leaves.) That leads to:

```
RN → "red" value
BN → "black" value
RT → BT RN BT
BT → L | T BN T
T  → BT | RT
```

which doesn't actually help, since the fourth production is still intractably ambiguous.

In fact, there is no way of disambiguating. Even if every `N` is labelled with its black-depth, it is still not possible to unambiguously build a tree from the in-order traverse.

Consider the following two trees:

```
       B                             B
      / \                           / \
     /   \                         /   \
     R    B                        R    B
    / \                           / \
   /   \                         /   \
   B    B                        B    B
    \                                /
     \                              /
      R                             R
```

Both of these are valid R-B trees, and have the in-order traverse:

```
B R R B B B
```

So we must conclude that there is insufficient information in the in-order traverse to reconstruct the original red-black tree.

An alternative problem would be constructing *some* valid red-black tree from an in-order traverse of a binary search tree. There is a bottom-up algorithm which will do that, which does not require the nodes to be annotated with their colour. Furthermore, the algorithm has O(1) complexity for each added node.

Although it cannot be expressed as a context-free grammar, you could use a predicated parser (i.e., a pushdown automaton augmented with attribute rules which furthermore can decide between two possible actions using synthesized attributes of the symbols.

I'm pretty sure I solved this problem once, but I don't have the solution handy and it doesn't surprise me that it is not easy to find on the internet. If it is what you're looking for, I'd suggest you start with [Ralph Hinze's 1999 paper](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/#P5) on red-black tree construction.